# How do I extract the first four characters via the 'sub' function?

Tags: r, date

I want to return the first four characters in the 'Date' column, so I only get the year.

I currently have the 'date' column, which I can see is a character string. I want to get the 'year' column.

I have used the "sub" function to retrieve the month for each date observation, where I used the following code:

```
FF5_class$Month <- sub(".*-", "", FF5_class$date)
```

How do I amend the above code to return the first 4 characters?

```
 Date     Year
1975-12   1975
1976-01   1976
1976-02   1976
```

Thank you !

Comment: You need to use `-.*` as your pattern

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substr`:

```
FF5_class$Month <- substr(FF5_class$date,1,4)
```